# Querying all objects in order of creation except for the latest one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

As the title explains, lets say I have the following queries:

```
    main_article = Article.objects.latest()
    prev_articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-created')
```

I want the `prev_articles` to not include the latest article (the object that is `main_article`). I tried looking this up, but can't seem to find a way to exclude the latest one while chaining `prev_articles`.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('-created')[1:]
except IndexError:
    articles = Article.objects.none()
```